# How do I import other python programmes in python scripts running on a Linux shared hosting?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a simple script called Hello.py, which works well in called directly from a web-browser.

The issue I have is that when I add `from abc import cde` (where abc.py is the file and cde is the module/function in it) it just prints the topmost print command and then does nothing.

This is being run on a shared hosting running python 2.6.6 (I have created a virtual env for ver3.5.2, and Linux.

Any assistance or insights appreciated.

Hello.py looks like -

```
#!/home/username/.local/bin/python3
print('Content-Type: text/html\n\n')
print ("Hello\n\n")

from pull import pull

pull()
```

Comment: Could you post some source code from `pull`?

Comment: add remaining code in try catch block and paste the error.

Answer (score 0):

Pull looks like this,

1. All other imports are custom Python Files meant to create or assist.
2. They exist in the same folder and have 755 permissions.
3. There are no errors displayed either on running the script (Hello.py) and pull.py works splendidly via terminal/SSH.

   ## !/home/username/.local/bin/python3

   print('\n\n\a---------------------------Beginning Pull------------------------\r\n\r')

   import pandas as pd

   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

   from CreationModule import createFiles,createFolders,writeFile

   from NSEanalysis import NSE

   df = pd.read_csv('Datasets/MC_Master.csv')

   today = pd.datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

   fmt = '%H%M%S'

   Time = pd.datetime.now().strftime(fmt)

   Y = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)

   Yesterday = Y.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

   folder = 'Nifty50/' + today+ '/'

   Yfolder = 'Nifty50/' + Yesterday + '/'

   e = len(df)
   print(e)

   crtFil = createFiles()

   crtFol = createFolders()

   crtFol.Nifty50()

   a = 0

   def pull():

   ```
   a = 0

   try:

       for r in df['Symbol']:

           print(a+1,'---------->', r)

           wrtFil = writeFile()

           wrtFil.QuandlPull(r)

           a += 1

        if a == e:

            print('We are done', a, ' of ', e)

   except:

       pull()

       a +=1
   ```

   return()

   pull()

   NSE()